# Form State in the field instance settings form

Tags: entities, ajax

How do I access the global form state of the field instance settings form. hook_field_instance_settings_form only takes two arguments - instance and field.

Use case - Ajax refresh of an options list

Answer (score 2):

You can't access it directly, what you can do it use `#after_build` which will be called with the `$form_state`, but this will happen at a later step.